# My dqn doesnt't work well: reward doesn't change, loss continues to increase

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, openai-gym, keras-rl

I'm trying to train Gradius with gym-retro and DQNAgent of keras-rl, but it doesn't work well. reward doesn't increase, loss continues to increase. I can't understand what is wrong.

A part of output is bellow.

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 30, 28)        8224      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 15, 64)        28736     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 15, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 15360)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               3932416   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 36)                9252      
=================================================================
Total params: 4,015,556
Trainable params: 4,015,556
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
Training for 1500000 steps ...
    2339/1500000: episode: 1, duration: 47.685s, episode steps: 2339, steps per second: 49, episode reward: 2500.000, mean reward: 1.069 [0.000, 100.000], mean action: 19.122 [0.000, 35.000], mean observation: 0.029 [0.000, 0.980], loss: 36.018083, mean_absolute_error: 11.380395, mean_q: 18.252860
    3936/1500000: episode: 2, duration: 51.391s, episode steps: 1597, steps per second: 31, episode reward: 1800.000, mean reward: 1.127 [0.000, 100.000], mean action: 19.312 [0.000, 35.000], mean observation: 0.027 [0.000, 0.980], loss: 64.386497, mean_absolute_error: 54.420486, mean_q: 68.424599
    6253/1500000: episode: 3, duration: 75.020s, episode steps: 2317, steps per second: 31, episode reward: 3500.000, mean reward: 1.511 [0.000, 100.000], mean action: 16.931 [0.000, 35.000], mean observation: 0.029 [0.000, 0.980], loss: 177.966461, mean_absolute_error: 153.478119, mean_q: 177.061630




#(snip)





 1493035/1500000: episode: 525, duration: 95.634s, episode steps: 2823, steps per second: 30, episode reward: 5100.000, mean reward: 1.807 [0.000, 500.000], mean action: 19.664 [0.000, 35.000], mean observation: 0.034 [0.000, 0.980], loss: 26501204410368.000000, mean_absolute_error: 86211024.000000, mean_q: 90254256.000000
 1495350/1500000: episode: 526, duration: 78.401s, episode steps: 2315, steps per second: 30, episode reward: 2500.000, mean reward: 1.080 [0.000, 100.000], mean action: 18.652 [0.000, 34.000], mean observation: 0.029 [0.000, 0.980], loss: 23247718449152.000000, mean_absolute_error: 84441184.000000, mean_q: 88424568.000000
 1497839/1500000: episode: 527, duration: 84.667s, episode steps: 2489, steps per second: 29, episode reward: 3700.000, mean reward: 1.487 [0.000, 500.000], mean action: 21.676 [0.000, 35.000], mean observation: 0.034 [0.000, 0.980], loss: 23432217493504.000000, mean_absolute_error: 80286264.000000, mean_q: 83946064.000000
done, took 49517.509 seconds
end!
```

The program is running on my university's server, I'm connecting the server with SSH.

A result of "pip freeze" is bellow.

```
absl-py==0.7.1
alembic==1.0.10
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astor==0.8.0
async-generator==1.10
attrs==19.1.0
backcall==0.1.0
bleach==3.1.0
certifi==2019.3.9
certipy==0.1.3
cffi==1.12.3
chardet==3.0.4
cloudpickle==1.2.1
cryptography==2.6.1
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.4.0
defusedxml==0.6.0
EasyProcess==0.2.7
entrypoints==0.3
future==0.17.1
gast==0.2.2
google-pasta==0.1.7
grpcio==1.21.1
gym==0.13.0
gym-retro==0.7.0
h5py==2.9.0
idna==2.8
ipykernel==5.1.0
ipython==7.5.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
jedi==0.13.3
Jinja2==2.10.1
jsonschema==3.0.1
jupyter-client==5.2.4
jupyter-core==4.4.0
jupyterhub==1.0.0
jupyterhub-ldapauthenticator==1.2.2
jupyterlab==0.35.6
jupyterlab-server==0.2.0
Keras==2.2.4
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0
kiwisolver==1.1.0
ldap3==2.6
Mako==1.0.10
Markdown==3.1.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.0.3
mistune==0.8.4
nbconvert==5.5.0
nbformat==4.4.0
notebook==5.7.8
numpy==1.16.4
oauthlib==3.0.1
pamela==1.0.0
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.4.0
pexpect==4.7.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
pipenv==2018.11.26
prometheus-client==0.6.0
prompt-toolkit==2.0.9
protobuf==3.8.0
ptyprocess==0.6.0
pyasn1==0.4.5
pycparser==2.19
pycurl==7.43.0
pyglet==1.3.2
Pygments==2.4.0
pygobject==3.20.0
pyOpenSSL==19.0.0
pyparsing==2.4.0
pyrsistent==0.15.2
python-apt==1.1.0b1+ubuntu0.16.4.2
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-editor==1.0.4
PyVirtualDisplay==0.2.4
PyYAML==5.1.1
pyzmq==18.0.1
requests==2.21.0
scipy==1.3.0
Send2Trash==1.5.0
six==1.12.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.3
tensorboard==1.14.0
tensorflow==1.14.0
tensorflow-estimator==1.14.0
tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.8.2
testpath==0.4.2
tornado==6.0.2
traitlets==4.3.2
unattended-upgrades==0.1
urllib3==1.24.3
virtualenv==16.5.0
virtualenv-clone==0.5.3
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.15.4
wrapt==1.11.2
xvfbwrapper==0.2.9
```

I'm suspecting first conv2d layer have something issue, and maybe it related to window_length of SequentialMemory. I'm thinking first conv2d layer doesn't take or convolute correctly. so I sorted batch in process_state_batch of CustomProcessor class. But The problem wasn't solved.

All I wrote is here.

```
#import all i need

import retro
import keras as k
import numpy as np
import rl
import rl.memory
import rl.policy
import rl.agents.dqn
import rl.core
import sys
import gym
from PIL import Image

import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend import tensorflow_backend

config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True))
session = tf.Session(config=config)
tensorflow_backend.set_session(session)

#set window size
win_size = (112,120)

#set log file
fo = open('log.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = fo

from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()

"""
keras add extra dimension for batch.
and add history dimention for SequentialMemory.
but conv2d isn't able to accept 5D input.
so i'd made my processor class.
CustomProcessor convert RGB input into Gray input.

and conv2d layer convolute data which's shape (win_len, win_hei, history).
so transpose batch.

for more information, ref url bellow.
https://github.com/keras-rl/keras-rl/issues/229
"""

class CustomProcessor(rl.core.Processor):

    def process_observation(self, observation):
        img = Image.fromarray(observation)
        img = img.resize(win_size).convert('L')
        tes = np.array(img) / 255
        return np.array(img) / 255


    #def process_state_batch(self, batch):
        #batch = batch.transpose(0,2,3,1)
        #print(batch.shape)
        #return batch


myprocessor = CustomProcessor()

"""
Gradius have action space which can take 9 action in same moment.
so i gotta discrete action space.
the way i'd taken is wrapping env class.
"""

class Discretizer(gym.ActionWrapper):

    def __init__(self, env):
        super(Discretizer, self).__init__(env)
        self._actions = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
               [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
               [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
               [0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],]
        for i in range(8):
            self._actions.append((np.array(self._actions[1]) + np.array(self._actions[i + 4])).tolist())
        for i in range(8):
            self._actions.append((np.array(self._actions[2]) + np.array(self._actions[i + 4])).tolist())
        for i in range(8):
            self._actions.append((np.array(self._actions[3]) + np.array(self._actions[i + 4])).tolist())
        self.actions = []
        for action in self._actions:
            env.get_action_meaning(action)
        self.action_space = gym.spaces.Discrete(len(self._actions))

    def action(self, a):
        return self._actions[a].copy()

env = retro.make(game="Gradius-Nes", record="./Record")
env = Discretizer(env)

import retro
import keras as k
import numpy as np
import rl
import rl.memory
import rl.policy
import rl.agents.dqn
import rl.core

import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend import tensorflow_backend

config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True))
session = tf.Session(config=config)
tensorflow_backend.set_session(session)

nb_actions = env.action_space.n

normal = k.initializers.glorot_normal()
model = k.Sequential()
win_len = 4
model.add(k.layers.Conv2D(
    32, kernel_size=8, strides=4, padding="same",
    input_shape=(4,120,112), kernel_initializer=normal,
    activation="relu", data_format='channels_first'))
print("chack")
model.add(k.layers.Conv2D(
    64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same",
    kernel_initializer=normal,
    activation="relu"))
model.add(k.layers.Conv2D(
    64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="same",
    kernel_initializer=normal,
    activation="relu"))
model.add(k.layers.Flatten())
model.add(k.layers.Dense(256, kernel_initializer=normal,
                         activation="relu"))
model.add(k.layers.Dense(nb_actions,
                         kernel_initializer=normal,
                         activation="linear"))

memory = rl.memory.SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=win_len)
policy = rl.policy.EpsGreedyQPolicy()

"""
dqn = rl.agents.DQNAgent(processor=myprocessor, model=model, nb_actions=nb_actions, memory=memory, nb_steps_warmup=10,
               target_model_update=1e-2, policy=policy)
"""
dqn = rl.agents.DQNAgent(processor=myprocessor, model=model, nb_actions=nb_actions, memory=memory, nb_steps_warmup=1000,
               target_model_update=1e-2, policy=policy)

dqn.compile(k.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
print(model.summary());
hist = dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=1500000, visualize=False, verbose=2)
print("end!")
dqn.save_weights("test_model.h5f", overwrite=True)

env.close()
```

ps:

I tried these solution.
1,add maxpooling layer and dense layer
2,use gradient clipping
3,down Adam's rl
but it still doesn't work. The code is bellow.

```
#import all i need

import retro
import keras as k
import numpy as np
import rl
import rl.memory
import rl.policy
import rl.agents.dqn
import rl.core
import sys
import gym
from PIL import Image

import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend import tensorflow_backend

config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True))
session = tf.Session(config=config)
tensorflow_backend.set_session(session)

#set window size
win_size = (224,240)

#set log file
#fo = open('log.txt', 'w')
#sys.stdout = fo

from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()

"""
keras add extra dimension for batch.
and add history dimention for SequentialMemory.
but conv2d isn't able to accept 5D input.
so i'd made my processor class.
CustomProcessor convert RGB input into Gray input.

and conv2d layer convolute data which's shape (win_len, win_hei, history).
so transpose batch.

for more information, ref url bellow.
https://github.com/keras-rl/keras-rl/issues/229
"""

class CustomProcessor(rl.core.Processor):

    def process_observation(self, observation):
        img = Image.fromarray(observation)
        img = img.resize(win_size).convert('L')
        tes = np.array(img) / 255
        return np.array(img) / 255


    #def process_state_batch(self, batch):
        #batch = batch.transpose(0,2,3,1)
        #print(batch.shape)
        #return batch


myprocessor = CustomProcessor()

"""
Gradius have action space which can take 9 action in same moment.
so i gotta discrete action space.
the way i'd taken is wrapping env class.
"""

class Discretizer(gym.ActionWrapper):

    def __init__(self, env):
        super(Discretizer, self).__init__(env)
        self._actions = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
               [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
               [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
               [0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],]
        for i in range(8):
            self._actions.append((np.array(self._actions[1]) + np.array(self._actions[i + 4])).tolist())
        for i in range(8):
            self._actions.append((np.array(self._actions[2]) + np.array(self._actions[i + 4])).tolist())
        for i in range(8):
            self._actions.append((np.array(self._actions[3]) + np.array(self._actions[i + 4])).tolist())
        self.actions = []
        for action in self._actions:
            env.get_action_meaning(action)
        self.action_space = gym.spaces.Discrete(len(self._actions))

    def action(self, a):
        return self._actions[a].copy()

env = retro.make(game="Gradius-Nes", record="./Record")
env = Discretizer(env)

import retro
import keras as k
import numpy as np
import rl
import rl.memory
import rl.policy
import rl.agents.dqn
import rl.core

import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend import tensorflow_backend

config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True))
session = tf.Session(config=config)
tensorflow_backend.set_session(session)

nb_actions = env.action_space.n

normal = k.initializers.glorot_normal()
model = k.Sequential()
win_len = 4
model.add(k.layers.Conv2D(
    32, kernel_size=8, strides=4, padding="same",activation="relu", 
    input_shape=(win_len,240,224), kernel_initializer=normal, data_format="channels_first"))
model.add(k.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='same', data_format="channels_first"))
model.add(k.layers.Conv2D(
    64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same",activation="relu", 
    kernel_initializer=normal, data_format="channels_first"))
model.add(k.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='same', data_format="channels_first"))
model.add(k.layers.Conv2D(
    64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="same",activation="relu", 
    kernel_initializer=normal, data_format="channels_first"))
model.add(k.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='same', data_format="channels_first"))
model.add(k.layers.Flatten())
model.add(k.layers.Dense(1024, kernel_initializer=normal, activation="relu"))
model.add(k.layers.Dense(1024, kernel_initializer=normal, activation="relu"))
model.add(k.layers.Dense(nb_actions,
                         kernel_initializer=normal,
                         activation="linear"))

memory = rl.memory.SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=win_len)
policy = rl.policy.EpsGreedyQPolicy()

"""
dqn = rl.agents.DQNAgent(processor=myprocessor, model=model, nb_actions=nb_actions, memory=memory, nb_steps_warmup=10,
               target_model_update=1e-2, policy=policy)
"""
dqn = rl.agents.DQNAgent(processor=myprocessor, model=model, nb_actions=nb_actions, memory=memory, nb_steps_warmup=50000,
               target_model_update=1e-6, policy=policy)

dqn.compile(k.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-7, clipnorm=1.), metrics=['mae'])
print(model.summary());
hist = dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=750000, visualize=False, verbose=2)
print("end!")
dqn.save_weights("test_model.h5f", overwrite=True)

env.close()
```